# Can perforce have two clients for the same view?

Tags: synchronization, root, perforce

I have a perforce client perforce.clientA that has the following view mapped

```
//allprojects/... //perforce.clientA/...
```

I then created a client for a particular project under all projects perforce.clientB

/`/allprojects/myProject/... //perforce.clientB/ ...`

When I run p4 sync for clientB it fails with the error,

```
Path '/location/to/clientB/...' is not under client's root 'location/to/clientA'.
```

Is it possible for a project to be in two client spaces? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the sync for clientB, you need to tell the server that you're syncing clientB; the error message suggests that you've told the server you're using clientA (probably implicitly via an environment variable), but you gave it a local path that goes with clientB and can't be translated via clientA's mapping.  The way to explicitly specify a client spec for a particular command is the -c global option, e.g.:

```
p4 -c clientB sync
```

This is obviously cumbersome for regular use; the easier method is to create a P4CONFIG file for each client, e.g.:

```
p4 set P4CONFIG=.p4config
echo P4CLIENT=clientA>/location/to/clientA/.p4config
echo P4CLIENT=clientB>/location/to/clientB/.p4config
```

Once you've done that, cd'ing to a location under the client root switches you to that client.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.